# PHP File Path on Mac for Processing Files

Tags: php, path

I am trying to do some file processing however I am struggling with the path. This is the full path for the text file I am trying to get together however it keeps saying error. Can somebody please help me with this as I have no idea why it is wrong because this is the path given on the text files info. I am also on Mac.

```
$path = ‘/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/Orhan/NetBeansProjects/PHPLabs/branches.txt‘;
```

Comment: If the error is a syntax error, then it's because you are using apostrophes and not quotes around the statement.

Comment: Please provide the full error notice.

Comment: Also, in this file do `echo __DIR__;` and see where the path is, then set the path in relation to that path: `$path = __DIR__.'/PHPLabs/branches.txt';`

Comment: @Rasclatt how do I see the outcome of the  echo __DIR__;

Comment: Where ever this `$path` is on the page, just before it write `echo __DIR__;`

Comment: But if it's a syntax error that is stopping the page, it won't come up until you fix that syntax error, which was noted above.

Comment: Thanks bro you figured it out!